# Tracing .Net Framework 1.0 usage

Tags: .net

In order to check whether i can safely uninstall the 
.Net Framework 1.0, i was wondering if i could track 
the framework usage.

1)
Would it be a good idea to scan every "exe" and "dll" 
and check if they force the loading of .Net Framework 
1.0? I'm afraid it's time expensive and Hard Disk 
stressing.

2)
Would it be a good idea to monitor (in real time), for 
a week, the loading of .Net Applications and log those 
who load .Net 1.0? How to monitor, hook the loader or 
what?

3)
Is there already a tool that does what i'm looking for?

I'll have to take a look at: Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)

Regards

---

Maybe i could write some software that periodically scans the active processes and checks which of them is linked against mscorlib.dll. If mscorlib's version is 1.0.xxxx that's a hit in .Net 1.0 usage.

I don't know if this catches all the cases in which the framework is involved, though.

---

@MystereMan - Repartition is an option i was considering, but i don't feel very comfortable with playing with full partitions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to uninstall the .NET 1.0 Framework? It isn't "harmful" to have it there.

Comment: This sounds to me like a strange variant of "premature optimization". Do you really *have* to uninstall it?

Comment: I have to install .Net 4.0. It seems it takes 600-850 Mb. I need to find some space. I see .Net 1.0 is using 865 Mb!

Comment: There are lots of ways to clear up space, but maybe you should just get a bigger hard drive.. they're not that expensive.  Still, have you tried turning on disk compression for folders you don't use often?  Have you cleared all your temporary folders?  Run the disk space optimization wizard?

Comment: It's Win XP, installed years ago. 
I thought a 10GB partition would have 
been enough. And, at the time, it was.

Comment: @BlueMoon - so repartition.  There's lots of tools to do that.  Or you can span two partitions to make a single one with NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others, there is no reason to uninstall it, unless you're short on disk space.  Even then, it's better to upgrade your disk in my opinion.

However, doesn't it seem obvious that the answer is, just uninstall it and see if anything breaks.  You can always reinstall it if something does.